# want to use a variable in one (for) loop in the next in C

Tags: c, cs50

I am a beginner, and am trying to do cs50 mario left half of a pyramid
something like this ( imaging s is just empty space)

```
ssss#
sss##
ss###
s####
```

after a lot of thinking i figured this formula should work

```
 #include<cs50.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)

{
 int n = get_int("Height: ");
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {

  // s stands for spaces
    for (int s = 0; s < n - 1 - i; s++)


       printf(" ");

  // h stands for hashes
    for (int h = 0; h < n - s; h++)
       printf("#");
       printf("\n");

 }

printf("\n");
}
```

as you see i want to use the variable s value which is changing and use it in the next variable h
i know that its value is only withing the ()
when i tried to add { } like this

```
#include<cs50.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)

{
 int n = get_int("Height: ");
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {

  // s stands for spaces
    for (int s = 0; s < n - 1 - i; s++)

{
       printf(" ");


  // h stands for hashes
    for (int h = 0; h < n - s; h++)
       printf("#");
       printf("\n");
       }

 }

printf("\n");
}
```

it avoids the printf(" ") line and prints # first which result in some thing like this

```
 
####
###
##
####
###
####
```

so how can i get it to first print spaces by the number of ( INput-1-line) then print hashes (Input-  variable hashes)
so that in the 2nd line of a 4 lines pyramid i get ( 4-1-1=2 spaces) then hashes(input- spaces) ( 4-2= 2)
 ss##
3rd line (4-1-2=1)(4-3=1)
 s###
and so on.

Comment: the first for loop `for (int h = 0; h < n - s; h++)` doesn't have brackets around the code block, and the second one doesn't even compile because it lacks the open bracket `for (int h = 0; h < n - s; h++)`

Comment: You have rather random indentation and spacing, and some of the braces `{` and `}` are peculiarly placed (AFAICS).  I think those misplaced braces account for some of the odd output.  It makes life so much easier for everyone if you use a standard layout for the code.  At the end of the `s` loop, the value of `s` would be `n - 1 - i`; you can use the in the limit expression of the next loop: `for (int h = 0; h < n - (n - 1 - i); h++)`, but then you can simplify it to `for (int h = 0; h < i + 1; h++)`, so you really don't need to be able to access `s` after the loop ends.

Comment: @phuclv: the code in the question does compile — but its loop structure is not what's intended and the indentation is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the index variable (`s`) outside the loop, so that it will retain its value once the loop ends for you to do with whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

A variable declared in a `for`-loop is not accessible outside the scope of this loop. If you want to access a variable outside the loop, define/declare it outside of the loop; for example:

```
// s stands for spaces
int s;
for (s=0; s < n - 1 - i; s++) {
   printf(" ");
}

// h stands for hashes
for (int h = 0; h < n - s; h++) { 
   ...
```

Comment: thank you i tried adding int s; but the  error ((declaration shadows a local variable [-Werror,-Wshadow)) would appear.. turned out i needed to add {}

Answer (score 1):

If I copy and format the code from the question, it looks like this:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n = get_int("Height: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        // s stands for spaces
        for (int s = 0; s < n - 1 - i; s++)
        {
            printf(" ");
            // h stands for hashes
            for (int h = 0; h < n - s; h++)
                printf("#");
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

The loop structure is not what was intended; the `h` loop can access `s`, but it shouldn't be able to.  The `i` loop counts from zero up to (but not including) the number entered.  You want to print `i + 1` hashes, so there's really no need to access `s` after the loop.

As I noted in a comment, at the end of the s loop, the value of `s` would be `n - 1 - i`; you can use that in the limit expression of the next loop: `for (int h = 0; h < n - (n - 1 - i); h++)`, but then you can simplify it to `for (int h = 0; h < i + 1; h++)`, so you really don't need to be able to access `s` after its loop ends.

The output from this jumbled loop code for height 7 looks like:

```
Height: 7
 #######
 ######
 #####
 ####
 ###
 ##
 #######
 ######
 #####
 ####
 ###
 #######
 ######
 #####
 ####
 #######
 ######
 #####
 #######
 ######
 #######
```

If you fix the code so that the `h` loop is not inside the `s` loop and fix the limit on the `h` loop as discussed, you end up with code like:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n = get_int("Height: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        // s stands for spaces
        for (int s = 0; s < n - 1 - i; s++)
            printf(" ");
        // h stands for hashes
        for (int h = 0; h < i + 1; h++)
            printf("#");
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

The corresponding output for height 7 is:

```
Height: 7
      #
     ##
    ###
   ####
  #####
 ######
#######
```

This looks like what is wanted.

Comment: thank you for your answer.. here is the final code taht worked for me and resulted in a full pyramid.
#include<cs50.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)

{
 int n;
 do
 {
  n = get_int("Height: ");
 }
 while (n < 0 || n > 50);
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {

  // s stands for spaces
  int s;
for (s=0; s < n - 1 - i; s++) {
   printf(" ");
}

// h stands for hashes
    for (int h = 0; h < n - s; h++)
       printf("#");

printf("  ");
  for(int h =0; h < n -s; h++)
  {printf("#");}

  printf("\n");
}
printf("\n");
}